# Puma won't keep listening after initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

It is an existing and working application that I have in other server, same deployment process and same versions of everything, but can't understand what's happening with Puma.

Initially thought that was an issue with the SystemD service, but it turns out that after puma invokation it ends instantly and does not keep listening.

It seems that configuration is loaded and no errors are made.

The command shows the info, but it ends immediately.

What can be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look in the log files.
Path to log files you can see in `config/production/puma.rb`